# 500 error during installation?

Tags: 7, installation

Trying to install the new [Drupal-COD Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/project/cod/) distribution, but got this error:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows

[image: screenshot]

Is this the sort of error one can overcome by increasing my `memory_limit` in the php.ini file?

Comment: Check your web server logs, it will give specific PHP error messages.  If it's a memory limit issue then it will be very straight-forward in the error log.

Comment: Where are my server logs? On IRC they told me it would be in `/var/log/httpd/`, but when I ls'd it: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 15 04:28 /var/log/httpd/error_log` :\ - BTW: I'm using Bluehost.

Comment: Finally found the logfile, here's its contents:

>[27-Aug-2012 09:37:35] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30720 bytes)

I'm sure it can be fixed by increasing my `memory_limit`.

:)

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=bluehost+boost+php+memory... first link.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the comment sign at "RewriteBase /" fixes my problem on migration of Drupal 7.
in the .htaccess file to fix.